# fbox and pythontex

Tags: pythontex

Why this does not work?

```
\fbox{
  \begin{pycode}
     print (1+1)
  \end{pycode}
 }
```

Is there a way around?

Comment: Could you expand your code to a MWE?

Comment: @Alenanno I have been preceded by egreg (see answer below).

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Please remember about it next time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `pycode` environment in the argument to another command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newsavebox{\pycodebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\pycodebox}
\begin{pycode}
print (1+1)
\end{pycode}
\end{lrbox}

\fbox{\usebox{\pycodebox}}

\end{document}
```

[image]